# Expire the Zend session if the user remains idle for 10 minutes

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, session-timeout, zend-session

I am new to zend and I want to ask how can I expire a user's session namespace's particular key if a user remains idle for 10 minutes. I have a namespace defined in zend session as

```
 $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('loginNamespace');
```

now when the user logs in I set the key loggedIn = 1 in session namespace. Now I want to expire not the whole session if the user remains idle but only that key. how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html#zend.session.advanced_usage.expiration), you can expire a key using:

```
$session->setExpirationSeconds( 600, 'key' );
```

So, how can you play with that? This way:

```
// Set "dummy" key with expiration
$session->setExpirationSeconds( 600, 'key' );

// Then, you can check if this key exists
if ( $session->key ) {
    // Just reset the expiration
    $session->setExpirationSeconds( 600, 'key' );
}
else {
    // Delete your other key
}
```

Comment: but it will expire the key even if user is not idle

Comment: how is it checking that if the user is idle or not ?

Comment: Because if it hasn't reset the key in 10 minutes, it means the user hasn't done anything in 10 minutes