# How to unset a variable pushed into a array stored in a session after a given time

Tags: php, arrays, security, session, zend-framework

In my PHP code using ZF1, I am generating security hases and storing them in an array as following:

```
$securityHash = Utility::generateSecurityToken();
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace();
$session->securityHashStore[] = $securityHash;
```

I am generating multiple hashes as you can see and storing them. Now, when a particular action has been performed which needs a hash, the hash corresponding to that action is validated removed from the array.

But now, I want to remove the `$securityHash` from the `securityHashStore` array, say 6000 seconds after it was created so that it is invalidated. However, the hashes generated less than 6000 seconds ago will not be removed.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

`securityHashStore` stores CSRF tokens for forms. These tokens are removed from the `securityHashStore` once the form corresponding to that CSRF is submitted. But now I need to handle the use case of user navigating away from the webpage and/or closing the `modal` containing the form. In that case, I want to remove the CSRF from the array.

Comment: Similar if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975781/expire-the-zend-session-if-the-user-remains-idle-for-10-minutes

Comment: ^But I dont want to unset a complete array,a value pushed into an array which is pushed into a session

Comment: What keys and values can be leveraged in the `securityHashStore` array?  Please edit your question to show what have you tried so far and what can be manipulated in the array.  (I am not a ZF1 user, perhaps a `zend-framework` tag would draw more specialized attention to your question)

Comment: `securityHashStore` stores CSRF tokens for forms. These tokens are removed from the `securityHashStore` once the form corresponding to that CSRF is submitted. But now I need to handle the use case of user navigating away from the webpage and/or closing the `modal` containing the form. In that case, I want to remove the CSRF from the array.